# Can't delete folder: rm: cannot remove: Directory not empty

Tags: windows, rm, windows-subsystem-for-linux, delete

I'm trying to delete a folder I once created and nothing happens when you try to remove the file in the file explorer.
I tried to remove the file per command line:

```bash
rm -rf folder-path/
```

This is where i get this error:

```
rm: cannot remove 'folder-path/': Directory not empty
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

I believe to have located the file that is causing the problem: a file under `ganache-core/node_modules/fetch-ponyfill/build` called `fetch-browser.js`
When i try to delete this file explicitly, I get:

```
rm: cannot remove 'fetch-browser.js': Invalid argument
```

I also can't open the file in any editor, it just gives me a warning as if the file didn't exist.

It seems to be some kind of ghost file that doesn't exist anymore but it still shows up and prevents me from deleting its parent folders.

Comment: A shot in the dark - but do you have a browser open when you try to delete the file? What Linux OS are you running in WSL? Please don't answer in comments, rather [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/741871/edit) the question to add new info so it gets more focused and everything relevant readily available.

Comment: I have a similar problem with an external NTFS disk. Did you fix your issue?